# detect if silentlogin is possible in adaljs-angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-active-directory, adal.js, microsoft-adal-angular6

I'm using the library adal-angular4@3.0.13 in a angular 6 project.
I try to do following:

1. If a silentlogin (login without prompting the user for credentials) with office365 is possible, then do a silentlogin (with `_adalService.login()`
2. If a silentlogin is not possible, then show a "login" button within a welcome-screen.

A silentlogin would be possible, when I'm authenticated to azure-ad / o365 and the cookie is still valid.

To find out, if a silentlogin is possible, i tried following:

```
try {
  let token = await this._adal.acquireToken(this._config.clientId).toPromise();
  return true;
} catch (e) {
  console.log('acquireToken error', e);
  return false;
}
```

But it always returns:

> User login is required

But when calling `_adalService.login()` it does a silentlogin.

**My question:**
How can i find out, if adaljs can login without prompting for credentials (it should be possible, like reading it from a o365-cookie)?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to determine whether silent login is available, you should pass `PlatformBehavior.Auto` to the `PlatformParameters` parameter of [`AcquireToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479460.aspx).

The problem is that adal.js doesn't actually support the needed overload and you cannot specify this value as `extraQueryParameter`. For a moment there, I thought you could use the `prompt` query parameter, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

At first glance, it seems that you can't do it then. But your error message gives the clue.

From the [adal.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/adal.js) source code, I can see that message is shown in this condition:

```
if (!this._user && !(this.config.extraQueryParameter && this.config.extraQueryParameter.indexOf('login_hint') !== -1)) {
    this.warn('User login is required');
    callback('User login is required', null, 'login required');
    return;
}
```

And in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow), the `login_hint` is described like this:

> Can be used to pre-fill the username/email address field of the sign
>   in page for the user, if you know their username ahead of time. Often
>   apps will use this parameter during re-authentication, having already
>   extracted the username from a previous sign-in using the
>   preferred_username claim.

... all of which makes a lot of sense when you're looking to do a silent authentication, but still need to say who you're authenticating for.

To finally answer the question, it seems you should add `'login_hint=myemail@example.com'` to your `config.extraQueryParameter`.

Comment: Thank you spending time on my problem. i saw this login_hint too, and i tried it now but it just prefills the username, when the user is getting prompt for credentials. I would imagine, that i don't have to store anything about the user (like opening a new browser tab in a browser where you're logged in to O365), and visit my application for the first time. In this case, my aim would be to direct login the user. if he hasn't got any O365 Session, i would like to redirect him to my welcome page, where he can click 'login' and getting redirect to the o365 login prompt.

Comment: It's a pity it doesn't help, because the `PlatformBehavior` overload is not available. Can't you use the presence of the session cookie as a guide?